# Using value field in td tag as hidden field in html table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I need to store some data linked to a cell in a HTML table.

Is there any reason *not* to use the value attribute in the td tag, like this? Is there maybe a better way to do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/uj36cxoL/1/

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td id="c00">00</td>
    <td id="c01">01</td>
    <td id="c02">02</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="c10">10</td>  
    <td id="c11">11</td>
    <td id="c12">12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
Col:
<select id="col">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
Row:
<select id="row">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<button id="getValue">Get value</button>
<script>
document.getElementById( "getValue" ).onclick = function()
{
    var col = document.getElementById( "col" ).value;
    var row = document.getElementById( "row" ).value;
    var cellId = "c" + col + row; //generate id of cell (e.g. c01)
    var cell = document.getElementById( cellId );
    alert( "The value of cell c" + col + row + "is: " + cell.value );
};
</script>

<script>
var count = 1;
for( var col = 0; col < 3; col++ )
{
    for( var row = 0; row < 6; row++ )
    {
        var cellId = "c" + col + row; //generate id of cell (e.g. c01)
        var cell = document.getElementById( cellId );
        cell.value = count++;
        cell.innerHTML = cell.innerHTML + " (value = " + cell.value + ")";
    }
}
</script>
```

I have tested this in IE, FF, Chrome and Opera on Windows, and it seems to work. It does not have to work on mobile devices.

Comment: You could use data attributes, with JQuery. https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: You can use `value` attribute..But using `data-*(data-value)` attributes, you can access them using `element.dataset` instead of `getAttribute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 has the ability to do this kind of thing baked in with **data attributes**. They allow you to store any data you may want to in any HTML tag to access it later as needed by simply accessing the .dataset.myData attribute of the DOM element in question. (In your case, this would be cell.dataset.whatever.) Although what you have now may work, it could also stop working at any time, since it's not an official standard of HTML5. The MDN page on data attributes is pretty good: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Incidentally, data attributes do work with JQuery, but like most things you can do with JQuery, you can also do it with regular JS without having to load the whole JQuery library.